# Funky caching versus Memcache versus...?

Tags: php, apache, caching, memcached

I'm working on a site that has an old, cgi+perl based embeddable widget. We're bringing the widget up to speed, and I was wondering about what patterns/methods to use for caching and if people knew of some method other than the two that I was thinking of:

1. Funky caching: the widgets have setting held in get params, and using rewrites we were going to have PHP create the file if it doesn't exist; Apache would then serve that file for subsequent requests until cron cleans it out.
2. Memcache/d: PHP can store the result in Memcache which apache could pull from the daemon (I presume). I imagine this could be done, but am uncertain at the moment about file/type and headers etc.

I've used #1 on many occasion, and #2 sounds like it could be an interesting alternative (if it can be done). Are there other good alternatives in this case? We're on a standard LAMP dedicated server.

The goal is to minimize server load when larger sites embed the widget (something we have been dealing with)...

**Added/Conclusion**

Okay, while I appreciate Piontek's effort at a solution, it would seem there's not much else out there (that anybody has shared). What we have realized though, is that the most efficient manner to handle this will be to gen one file only and have the client-side handle the get params and logic that builds the resulting widget.

Comment: Just to clarify; I'm wondering not so much about where we can optimize PHP or DB calls, but what would be a good caching strategy for the results of that process.

Answer (score 0):

For best results, I would use Memcache along with APC (http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php).  Memcache is more for caching database queries and improving performance in that regard, while APC is more for improving performance of PHP code. Together they can give you a very scalable system.

Comment: Thanks Piontek, I'm not certain why I hadn't thought of APC. In our case though, I would guess that the funky caching would be quicker as it bypasses PHP after the file is created, leaving the work of simply file serving and apache. So the process may be:

1 - PHP+memcache+APC for first build (funky-style).
2 - Apache+file for subsequent requests.
3 - Cron rms the files and we return to #1

Comment: If you are really concerned with performance, I would recommend taking a look at HipHop for PHP. HipHop is a "source code transformer" designed to reduce CPU and memory usage by transforming your PHP code into C++ code.

Comment: Thanks @Piontek Media, I had thought about this as well, but my question isn't so much about opcode caches or even using the compiler. Unless you think that could be faster than Apache serving a flat file?